# I need to insert massive dummy data into aws dynamodb

Tags: database, bash, shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I had to fill a dynamodb table with the test data. I was able to fill 10,000 items with below script:

```
for (( c = $1; c <= $2; c++ ))
do
    aws dynamodb put-item --table-name test_table \
    --item '{"swVersion":{"S": "x.x.'${c}'"}, .... \ 
    # multi-line item description goes on and on \
    # item size is about 2KB \
done
```

it was quite slow process so I had to split 1~1000, 1001~2000, and so on.
Now I am trying to insert 1,000,000 items. I am guessing I could use `batch-write`. with maybe running multiple scripts simultaneously (which I also unsure about how to do at this moment)  I would like some advices on below:

- Is there a more time/money efficient way than what I tried?
- How should I run multiple inserting script simultaneously?
- How the inserting method would be different when there is a `WCU` limit of 100 or 1,000 or 10,000?

Comment: Batch inserts, if available, are certainly the way to go for this kind of thing. Please ask separately if you have many disparate questions.

Comment: Also, why would you need to insert so much dummy data? If it's for testing purposes you're much better off with a mock.

Comment: I ended up using lots and lots of lambda functions for this task.  I had fun load-testing

Answer (score 1):

In fact yes, you could use batchwrite, and increase the provisioned write capacity, knowing that approximately 1 write capacity unit  for ~1ko data take 1 second, so you can increase it to 100 write capacity unit to write 100 row per second, ( do the math to calculate how long it will take, and increase if you need, more).
Also don't forget that batchwrite only accept 25 write at a time.

Read the [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ProvisionedThroughput.html#HowItWorks.ProvisionedThroughput.Manual)  and the [pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/dynamodb/pricing/)